# JSF 2: possible to initialize session-scoped beans on session start?

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection, jsf-2, managed-bean, session-scope

Is it possible in JSF 2 to initialize a session-scoped managed bean as soon as the session context is loaded? I know it's possible with Application Scoped beans and the `eager` attribute in the `@ManagedBean` annotation, but does something similar exist for session beans? I have a session-scoped bean that I want to have loaded regardless of if a specific page is visited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you need a bean? If it is some general initialization stuff, you can use a `HttpSessionListener`, and on `sessionCreated(..)` initialize things.

Comment: My understanding is that if the bean isn't `ApplicationScoped`, the regular, lazy-initialization is used. I was thinking about using a listener, but I just wanted to know if there was an easier way to accomplish this.

Comment: Bozho, no, see also 4th paragraph of `@ManagedBean` javadoc: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html