# StackOverflow error when initializing JSF SessionScoped bean in HttpSessionListener

Tags: jsf, servlets, jsf-2, httpsession, servlet-listeners

Continuing on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7960065/318287), I'm trying to initialize a session-scoped JSF bean when the application's session first starts, so the bean will be available to a user, regardless of which page they access on my web application first. My custom listener:

```
public class MyHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap()
                .get("mySessionBean") == null) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap()
                    .put("mySessionBean", new MySessionBean());
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is giving me a stack overflow error. It appears that the `put()` method in the `SessionMap` class tries to create a new `HttpSession`, thus causing an infinite loop to occur with my listener. How can I initialize a JSF session-scoped bean when my application's session first starts, without running into this issue?

I'm using JSF 2 with Spring 3, running on WebSphere 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session isn't been fully finished creating at that point. Only when the listener method leaves, the session is put into the context and available by `request.getSession()` as JSF's `getSessionMap()` is using under the covers.

Instead, you should be grabbing the session from the `event` argument and use its `setAttribute()` method. JSF lookups and stores session scoped managed beans just there and won't create a new one if already present.

```
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    event.getSession().setAttribute("mySessionBean", new MySessionBean());
}
```

Note that I removed the superfluous nullcheck as it's at that point **impossible** that the session bean is already there.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you should actually never rely on the `FacesContext` being present in an implementation which isn't managed by JSF. It is quite possible that the session can be created during a non-JSF request.